# How to add a grid to my program without that all of the rest of the program will be deleted?

Tags: wxpython, frame, wxgrid

This is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
from random import randint

OPTIONS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "DEL", 0, "SEND"]
# these are the events' IDs sent to a function when you click a button.
# the OPTIONS_ID is in the same order of OPTIONS.

OPTIONS_ID = [-31990,-31989,-31988,-31987,-31986,-31985, -31984, -31983, -31982, -31981, -31980, -31979]  # the built in wxpython IDs for the buttons


GAME_POSITION = (400, 100)
GAME_SIZE = [900, 600]

class Frame(wx.Frame):  # class for all the frames in our game.

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.fdf = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(275, 75), pos=(520, 20))
            self.count = 0




    # this function creates a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
    def write(self, panel, txt, pos, size=20, font_family=wx.SWISS, font_style = wx.NORMAL,font_weight = wx.BOLD, underline = False):
        # create a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
        your_txt = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, txt, pos)
        your_txt.SetFont(wx.Font(size,font_family,font_style,font_weight,underline))
    # same as above, just for a button.
    def create_button(self, panel, txt, position, width, height):
        Size = wx.Size(width, height)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, txt, position, Size)
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.border.Add(self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: self.OnButton(evt), self.button)
    def disable_button(self, panel, txt, position, width, height):
        Size = wx.Size(width, height)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, txt, position, Size)
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.border.Add(self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: self.OnButton(evt), self.button)
        self.button.Disable()
    def OnButton(self, event):
        print repr(event.Id) + ","
        if event.Id in OPTIONS_ID:  # if indeed an option button was pressed
            exited = -1  # exited is 5100 if the user exited his dialog box
            # assigning the events to the button.
            for i in range(12):
                if event.Id != -31981 and event.Id != -31979 and event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[i]:
                    self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[i]))
                    self.count += 1
                elif event.Id == -31979:
                    pass
            if event.Id == -31981:
                if self.count > 0:
                    self.count -= 1
                self.fdf.Remove(self.fdf.GetLastPosition()-1, self.fdf.GetLastPosition())
            if self.count == 4:
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                        try:
                            int(child.GetLabel())
                        except ValueError:
                            if child.GetLabel() == "SEND":
                                child.Enable()
                        else:
                            child.Disable()
            else:
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if child.GetLabel() != "SEND":
                        child.Enable()
                    else:
                        child.Disable()
                    if self.count == 0:
                        if child.GetLabel() == "DEL":
                            child.Disable()
            for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                    if child.GetLabel() in self.fdf.GetValue():
                        child.Disable()



class Game(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):  # upon game opening
        # I would like the options window to be the first window's parent
        # so I will first set up our options window:
        window = Frame(None, -1, "Good Luck!", GAME_POSITION, GAME_SIZE)
        first_panel = window.panel

        window.write(first_panel, "BULLS AND COWS!", (20, 20), size=(35))
        countX = 500
        countY = 100
        for option in OPTIONS:
            if str(option) == "SEND" or str(option) == "DEL":
                window.disable_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100)
            else:
                window.create_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100)
            countX += 110
            if str(option) == "3" or str(option) == "6" or str(option) == "9":
                countY += 110
                countX = 500



        window.Show(True)
        return True


def main():
    camel = Game()
    camel.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I am trying to do is to add a grid into the empty area, but for some reason the grid is shown in the whole frame, which hide the the other attributes of the panel. My question is how to add the grid normally to the panel, I mean without ruin the other program? I have tried to play with the position but for some reason it doesn't work, and I didn't find any information in the internet.
I will glad to get some help here. Thank you (:
By the way: the grid is with 10 rows and 3 cols.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you describe you would like your frame to look like. I don't see a 10 row by 3 col grid only the number input panel and you have done import wx.grid as gridlib but not used the import anywhere?

Comment: I would like my frame to be like the code in above, and a grid in addition in the left side (the empty side) of the frame. the problem is that i don't know how to create a grid that will be in that position - when i tried to build the grid, it filled the whole frame and not just the left side..
 you understand ?

Comment: I just imported the grid, but haven't used it already (since i don't know how to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you the right way it should work like this:

```
class Game(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):  # upon game opening
        # I would like the options window to be the first window's parent
        # so I will first set up our options window:
        window = Frame(None, -1, "Good Luck!", GAME_POSITION, GAME_SIZE)
        first_panel = window.panel

        #This lines of code add the grid to the frame
        grid = gridlib.Grid(first_panel) #the grid must created with a panel as argument  
        grid.CreateGrid(10,3) #create grid with 10 rows and 3 columns
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)  
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 50) #Border in all directions with 50 pixels width
        first_panel.SetSizer(sizer)  
        #grid has been added to the frame... continuing with your code         

        window.write(first_panel, "BULLS AND COWS!", (20, 20), size=(35))
        countX = 500
        countY = 100
...
```

You can also add the grid in a function of your Frame class it should work similar and depends on your application. 
I think the success of adding a grid without "destroying" the rest of your frame depends on the sizer. With the arguments above it should work.